# Why Html-Webpack-Plugin rather than simple html in react js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Hello I am new in react and for html template I found using html-webpack-plugin in tutorial. My question is why to use html-webpack-plugin if same task can be done by simple html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) provide an html template to your instance of html-webpack-plugin. What the plugin will do is insert the proper call(s) to your bundled app as well as the bundled CSS, if any, and generate a production version of your index.html file.

While it might not seem extraordinarily useful at first, it becomes very handy when you break your bundle into chunks (for instance, vendor, app, etc.) and/or when you add timestamp-based hashes to your bundled filenames (a task which can be automated in the webpack build process) in order to optimize cache management and file sizes. Consider that, if the resulting files weren't automatically inserted, you'd have to manually edit your index.html file *everytime* you rebuilt your app. Believe me, you do not want to do that.

You can also add specific directives inside your html template for conditional inserts, etc.

In the end, it's a very good quality of life plugin that will make your build process a lot easier.